# Grails Spring Security Core 2.0-RC4 issue "Sorry not able to find user with that ....."

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to secure a simple grails app.  Pulling my hair out trying to authenticate with an admin user created in BootStrap.groovy.

BootStrap.groovy:

```
class BootStrap {
    def springSecurityService

    def init = { servletContext ->

    def userRole = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?: new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true)
    def adminRole = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') ?: new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true)
    def adminUser = SecUser.findByUsername('admin') ?: new SecUser( username: 'admin', password: 'admin', enabled: true  ).save(failOnError: true)

    println(userRole.all)
    println(adminRole.getAuthority())
    println(adminUser.getUsername())

    if (!adminUser.authorities.contains(adminRole)) { SecUserSecRole.create( adminUser, adminRole ) }

    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured;

class EmployeeController {

    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
    def index() { 
        render "Some things are just private"
    }
//  def scaffold = true
}
```

Config.groovy:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'SecUser.SecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'SecUser.SecRoleReqeustmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'SecUser.Reqeustmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/employee/**':                   ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']
]
```

URLMapping.groovy:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "/login/$action?"(controller:"login")
        "/logout/$action?"(controller:"logout")
    }
}
```

Database.groovy:

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoreconnect=true"
        }
    }
```

......

added debugging but nothing shows up of value.

what am I missing?  When I get the default user login/auth page and I put in admin/admin credentials the application keeps returning with "Sorry not able to find user with that...."

Thank you in advance

Using the techniques identified in the post.  I got the following results:
I added the event handler directly to the config and it shed some more light on the error:
uthentication.ProviderManager – Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
ERROR auth failed for user admin: The specified user domain class ‘SecUser.SecRole’ is not a domain class
2014-09-30 18:48:43,076 [http-bio-9191-exec-6] DEBUG rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices – Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.
2014-09-30 18:48:43,076 [http-bio-9191-exec-6] DEBUG rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices – Cancelling cookie
2014-09-30 18:48:43,099 [http-bio-9191-exec-6] DEBUG web.DefaultRedirectStrategy – Redirecting to ‘/shareRef/login/authfail?login_error=1′

I’m not sure why springsecurity indicates that SecUser.SecRole is not a domain class.

I have a SecUserSecRole domain class that was automagically created after running the grails s2 script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a couple of blog posts describing some techniques you can use to diagnose issues like this - check out http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2003 and http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2029

Comment: From the error you posted in the blog comments, it looks like you have a domain class named `SecUser.SecRole` - is that correct? You can't have a period in the middle of a class name.

Comment: Thank you again for taking my questions.  SecUser.SecRole does not exist in my domain package so I'm not sure why its looking for that class.

Comment: Based on your inquiry about my SecUser.SecRole and your previous post on how to debug spring security, the solution to my problem was found.  The debugging indicated SecUser.SecRole was the name of the domain class even though that did not exist.  The problem was in my Config.groovy grails.plugin.springsecurity settings were wrong.  I updated the Config.groovy settings for userDomainClassName, authorityJointClassName and authority.className to be SecUser, SecUserSecRole and SecRole respectively and now it all works.

Comment: For documentation purposes: grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.onAbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   println "\nERROR auth failed for user $e.authentication.name: $e.exception.message\n"
} I used this to get the correct debug information to help solve the issue.